# Delete Elasticsearch document by ID with Scala using Java API

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm using Elastic Java API in Scala to delete a list of document, using their ID to delete them one at a time, no success for now.  API works fine for other calls like SearchResponse.
My code looks like this :

```
var deleteResp : DeleteResponse = null

deleteResp = ElasticSearch.getClient()
      .prepareDelete(index, type, id)
      .get()
```

Same with :

```
deleteResp = ElasticSearch.getClient()
      .prepareDelete(index, type, id)
      .execute()
      .actionGet()
```

I also tried to catch Elastic response for debugging using this, but nothing shows up in stdout.

```
try{ \ previous code } 
catch {
    case e: Exception => {
    print("Failed deletion", e.getMessage)
    e.printStackTrace() }
}
```

Config :
- Scala 2.10.6
- Spark 1.6
- Elasticsearch 2.3.2

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure about your index, type and id? can you find the document with `curl -XGET localhost:9200/index/type/id` ?

Comment: Ok, and you're sure that your client is properly connected to your ES server?

Comment: Same for connectivity, deletion part is actually the last step of the code. Before that, in run multiple queries to get JSON responses and process them without trouble.

Comment: But what kind of response do you actually get in `deleteResp` ?

Comment: Thing is I don't know how to catch the response, the try/catch block does not return any stackTrace, and printing the deleteResp var gives `org.elasticsearch.action.delete.DeleteResponse@5da55732`
However when I directly send a DELETE command in Sense it's working fine.

Comment: Ok, but `DeleteResponse` has methods (`getResult()`, etc) you can call in order to know the status of the call.

Comment: Thank you Val, I'm still trying to debug this.
The getResult() method doesn't seem to exist, in fact there's not a lot of options for DeleteResponse object according to : [Javadoc](http://xbib.org/elasticsearch/2.1.1/apidocs/org/elasticsearch/action/delete/DeleteResponse.html#method.summary)

Comment: Hmm indeed I was looking at the most recent version. What do you get when calling `getShardInfo()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's a pretty specific case but given the poor info on Java API usage, someone may find this case relevant.

Thank to Val and precise debugging I found the cause :
Be very careful on the string format passed to the prepareSearch().

My ID, coming from a List, contained brackets that messed things up, the delete request was successful but on a wrong ID.

For details, think about using all available methods on request objects and double check each formatting :

```
var deletedId = deleteResp.getId()
var deletedType = deleteResp.getType()
var deletedIndex = deleteResp.getIndex()
var deletedShard = deleteResp.getShardInfo()
```